# Risk free profit with a put option

Tags: finance

From Terence Tao Blog the price of a put option at time $t_0$ cannot exceed the strike price P at time $t_1$. The reason is that otherwise there would be an arbitrage opportunity. Everyone in the market could build a put option Simply putting aside a certain amount of cash for paying the strike price P. In this way could one make risk-free profit and how?

Comment: What do you mean?  Just sell the put  and keep $P$ out of the proceeds to pay for the asset if the put is exercised.  Even if that asset you are forced to buy is worthless, you keep the excess premium.

Comment: Unless you are worried about technicalities...I mean, it is technically possible for an asset to trade at a negative price.  It happens.  Tax residual CMO's, for instance, can carry excess tax liability so, sometimes, people need to be paid to accept the assets.  But, from the general context, I am assuming that you were speaking of ordinary assets which can certainly trade for $0$, but not lower.

Answer (score 0):

You are the seller, I am the buyer.

At $t_0$, I pay you $x$ to purchase a put option for $S$ at strike price $P$ at time $t_1$, meaning that at $t_1$ I can choose to force you to buy $S$ at price $P$.

Generally I will exercise this option if the market price of $S$ is far less than $P$ at $t_1$, I can buy $S$ off the market and force you to pay extra for it. (as the buyer of a put option, I am basically betting that the price of $S$ will decrease in the future)

If $x > P$, then you simply set aside $P$ and pocket $x-P$. Then at time $t_1$ even if $S$ is worthless and I force you to buy it you still come out ahead.

Of course, as a buyer I would never accept such a deal because I am guaranteed to lose money, so it's not really an arbitrage opportunity because no one would buy this option. Similarly "You give me \$2 and I will give you between \$0 and \$1 back" is also "risk-free profit" if you can find anyone gullible enough to take your offer.

Comment: you come out ahead because you earn x-P?

Comment: @Pirofotulis The words "you" and "me" are confusing. BaronVT's answer can be rephrased as: if the option buyer pays $x>P$ for the put option then the seller will always earn  at least $x-P$ which is an unjustified arbitrage profit.

Comment: @Kurt G. Yes i see. So the price at time $t_0$ cannot exceed P